# How to test an AngularJS provider configuration?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs

I have a provider defined as follows:

```
(function(angular) {

angular.module('myModule', [])
.provider('myService', function () {
    var service = {};
    service.configureSomething = function () { };
    service.$get = function () { return {}; };
    return service;
});

})(angular);
```

**How can I test `configureSomething()`?**

The example shown in the [AngularJS documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide) assumes the provider is a public function rather than being an anonymous function passed inside `.provider()` within a `(function(){})()` approach.

Please note that I don't want to test for the provider instance, I'm just interested in testing the configuration.

Comment: I answered this same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771810/how-to-test-angularjs-custom-provider/17378551#17378551) based upon Eitan Peer's answer to your Google Group question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's the answer provided by Mark Gemmill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771810/how-to-test-angularjs-custom-provider/17378551#17378551) based on Eitan Peer's answer to my same question posted in the AngularJS Google Groups.