# AngularJS Change Constant Value that gets passed to Config for Unit Test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Is there anyway to change the constant value that gets sent to the config function of the module for a Unit Test?

I have the following (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4nb739k5/2/)):

```
//--- CODE --------------------------
var module = angular.module("myApp", []);
module.constant("myConstant", "foo");
module.provider("awesomeStuff", function () {
    var value;

    this.setValue = function (val) {
        value = val;
    };

    this.$get = function () {
        return {
            myValue: value
        };
    };
});
module.config(function (myConstant, awesomeStuffProvider) {
    //want to mock myConstant
    awesomeStuffProvider.setValue(myConstant);
});



//--- SPECS -------------------------
describe("foo", function() {
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("myApp", function ($provide) {
        //Attempt to override the myConstant value that gets passed to config
        $provide.constant("myConstant", "bar");
    }));

  it("has a value of bar", inject(function(awesomeStuff, $injector) {
    expect($injector.get("myConstant")).toBe("bar");
    expect(awesomeStuff.myValue).toBe("bar");
  }));
});
```

I know this is a trivial example, but I want to know if its possible to get a different constant to be injected into the config... I know it is possible to get a reference to the provider and call setValue function from unit test (i.e. configuring provider via [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771810/how-to-test-angularjs-custom-provider/17378551#17378551)), but this is not what I'm looking for.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module("myApp"));
```

This will load the module and execute the registered config functions.

In your case you have:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module("myApp", function ($provide) {
    //Attempt to override the myConstant value that gets passed to config
    $provide.constant("myConstant", "bar");
}));
```

What happens now is basically the same as if you had the following:

```
var module = angular.module("myApp", []);

... Constant and Provider omitted ...

module.config(function(myConstant, awesomeStuffProvider) {

  awesomeStuffProvider.setValue(myConstant);
});

module.config(function($provide) {

  $provide.constant("myConstant", "bar");
});
```

As the registered config functions will be executed in order of registration this will not have the desired result.

If you need to mock a constant before it's used in any config function I would recommend to put it in a separate module.

Depending on your use case, you can now either:

1. Create two versions of this module - one for production and one for the tests
2. Create only the real version and mock the constant in the test

The second case would look something like this:

App:

```
angular.module("configuration", []).constant("myConstant", "foo");

var module = angular.module("myApp", ["configuration"]);

module.provider("awesomeStuff", function () {
    var value;

    this.setValue = function (val) {
        value = val;
    };

    this.$get = function () {
        return {
            myValue: value
        };
    };
});

module.config(function (myConstant, awesomeStuffProvider) {
    awesomeStuffProvider.setValue(myConstant);
});
```

Test:

```
describe("foo", function () {

    beforeEach(function () {

        angular.mock.module("configuration", function ($provide) {
            $provide.constant("myConstant", "bar");
        });

        angular.mock.module("myApp", function () {
            // Something else
        });
    });

    it("has a value of bar", inject(function (awesomeStuff, $injector) {
        expect($injector.get("myConstant")).toBe("bar");
        expect(awesomeStuff.myValue).toBe("bar");
    }));
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/f0nmbv3c/