# How to Jasmine Test if an angular service was actually created?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a code here that is a fork of `ng-wrap` which was inspired from [this article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2720-creating-and-extending-a-lodash-underscore-service-in-angularjs.htm). Basically, it creates an angular service for global variables introduced by third party libraries, this is to confirm with angularjs concept of dependency-injection. But I'm struggling on how to test if the 3rd party variable was actually converted to an angular service.

here is the code:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('blocks.wrapper', []);
})();


/* jshint ignore:start, -W101 */
// Inspired from http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2720-creating-and-extending-a-lodash-underscore-service-in-angularjs.htm
// Fork from https://github.com/bahmutov/ng-wrap
/* jshint ignore:end, +W101 */
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('blocks.wrapper')
    .provider('ngWrap', ngWrapProvider);

  ngWrapProvider.$inject = ['$provide'];
  /* @ngInject */
  function ngWrapProvider($provide) {
    /* jshint validthis:true */
    this.wrapper = wrapper;

    this.$get = function() {
      return {'wrapper': wrapper};
    };

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////// IMPLEMENTATION ///////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function wrapper(name, leaveGlobal) {
      $provide.provider(name, function () {
        if (typeof window[name] === 'undefined') {
          throw new Error('Cannot find window.' + name);
        }

        var thing = window[name];
        if (!leaveGlobal) {
          delete window[name];
        }

        this.$get = function() {
          return thing;
        };
      });
    }
  }
})();
```

I here is my test spec so far:

```
'use strict';

/* jshint -W117, -W030 */
describe('blocks.wrapper', function() {
  var ngWrapProvider;
  var ngWrap;
  var mocks = {
    windowProperty: {
      testProperty: 'testValue'
    }
  };

  beforeEach(module('blocks.wrapper', function (_ngWrapProvider_) {
    ngWrapProvider = _ngWrapProvider_;
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_ngWrap_) {
    ngWrap = _ngWrap_;
  }));

  describe('ngWrapProvider', function() {
    it('should successfuly be defined', inject(function() {
      expect(ngWrapProvider).toBeDefined();
    }));

    it('should have a wrapper method', function() {
      expect(ngWrapProvider.wrapper).toBeDefined();
    });
  });

  describe('ngWrap', function() {
    it('should successfuly be defined', function() {
      expect(ngWrap).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should have a wrapper method', function() {
      expect(ngWrap.wrapper).toBeDefined();
    });
  });

  it('should have ngWrapProvider.wrapper & ngWrap.wrapper point to the same function', function() {
    expect(ngWrapProvider.wrapper).toEqual(ngWrap.wrapper);
  });

  describe('wrapper method', function() {
    it('should throw an error when window.property is undefined', function() {
      expect(function() { ngWrapProvider.wrapper('_'); }).toThrow();
      expect(function() { ngWrap.wrapper('_'); }).toThrow();
    });
  });
});
```

I'm relatively new to testing, so I'm probably doing it all wrong. And although, yes, all the test specs above passes, but I'm struggling on how I would test that `window.property` was actually converted into an angular service.

Here are my attempts so far:

```
describe('wrapper method', function() {
  ...
  it('should convert window.property to an angular service', inject(function($injector) {
    window._ = mocks.windowProperty;
    ngWrapProvider.wrapper('_');
    $injector.invoke(ngWrapProvider);
    expect(angular.injector().has('_')).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

The above gives an error of:
`Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got ngWrapProvider`

if I try to remove the line with $injector entirely, then `expect(angular.injector().has('_')).toBeTruthy();` always return false.

I got the idea of the whole $injector thing from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26674136/2475170)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I resolve my problem, `$injector.invoke` wants a function as a parameter, so what I did is wrap `ngWrapProvider.wrapper('_');` inside a function, then make that function the parameter for `$injector.invoke`.

Then I create an `it` statement which takes/injects the new `_` service inside of it. And if it's defined and equates to my mock `window._` then I can say that the service was indeed created and is referencing the correct object in the global scope.

Below is the actual code that I used.

```
describe('wrapper method', function() {
  ...
  describe('with window.property', function() {
    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
      window._ = mocks.windowProperty;
      $injector.invoke(function () {
        ngWrapProvider.wrapper('_');
      });
    }));

    it('should expose window.property as an angular service', inject(function(_) {
      expect(_).toBeDefined();
      expect(_).toEqual(mocks.windowProperty);
    }));

    ...
  });
});
```