# Angular, testing custom provider and config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have a provider that gets items set in it with a contructor, then returns a $get with a few functions for use. The issue is the $get functions all use an object that is set with the constructor I have, And I would like to be able to set the constructor for testing (or maybe a different approach?). Here is what I have.

The provider (as built for requirejs)

```
  function URLprovider(angular, URLfactory, underscore) {
     var metadata = {
         componentName: 'URLprovider',
         moduleName: 'test.URLprovider'
     };

     $moduleObjectProvider.$inject = [];

     function $moduleObjectProvider() {

         var currentModules = {};

         function modulePush(currentModule, name) {
                 var tempMod = {};
                 tempMod[name] = currentModule;
                 _.extend(currentModules, tempMod);
             }

        //constructor
         this.moduleConstructor = function(name, cb) {
             if (!currentModules[name]) {
                 this.states = [];
                 this.callback = cb;
                 modulePush(this, name);
             }
         };

         this.$get = $get;

         $get.$inject = ['URLfactory', '$log', '$location'];

         function $get(URLfactory, $log, $location) {

             return {
                 go: function(name, stateName, options) {

                 },
                 prep: function(name, stateName, options) {

                 },
                 modules: function() {
                     return currentModules;
                 }
             };
         }
     }

     angular.module(metadata.moduleName, []).provider(metadata.componentName, $moduleObjectProvider);
```

So - the functions I want to test are in the $get. If I console.log URLprovider in the test I ONLY get back the functions in the get. Each of those get functions uses the currentModules variable that is set with the constructor. So, in a normal scenario I would just set it in a config, something like -

```
  .config(function(URLproviderProvider) {
                 var callback = function(name, obj) {
            console.log(name, obj);
        }

        var mod = new URLproviderProvider.moduleConstructor("module1,", callback)
            .addState("calender", ["day", "week", "month"]);


    })
```

So that would push that object into currentModules. I need to do this for testing essentially, as all the functions in the $get will not run correctly without something inside the currentModules.

So what I'm wondering is -

Is there a way to fake the variable currentModules when testing?

Is there a way to kind of mock the config to set the currentModules (in the beforeEach) for testing, I feel like I would need to expose the constructor differently (I'm not sure how right now) because when I log URLprovider in the tests, it just returns the functions in the $get, I don't think I have access to it in there?

Or should I approach this in another way?

I am using Karma, Chai, and Sinon. Thanks!

Bump!

Edit:

So I tried exposing the constructor to the testing via putting it into the $get - like

```
     moduleConstructor: function(name, cb) {
         if (!currentModules[name]) {
             this.states = [];
             this.callback = cb;
             modulePush(this, name);
         }
     };
```

However, inside the get, the this reference is now off, (we are inside a this.$get). If I could expose the constructor, I could call it to push a new into it and test via that. If i try to log a this inside the function in the get, the this references the entire get.

So having a this.moduleConstructor function outside lets me call a new on how I want it to act.

Edit: Bump! Still cant figure this one out :(

Answer (score 1):

I found a very good answer in the post [How to test AngularJS custom provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771810/how-to-test-angularjs-custom-provider), especially the answer from Stephane Catala (Apr 22) that gives a generic function providerGetter that gives you access to a provider in a Jasmine test. You can also access the service the provider provides. Using that function (in Jasmine) you can do something like this:

```
describe("provider test", function() {
  var infoProvider, info;

  function providerGetter(moduleName, providerName) {
    var provider;
    module(moduleName, 
       [providerName, function(Provider) { provider = Provider; }]);
    return function() { inject(); return provider; }; 
  }

  beforeEach(function() {
    infoProvider = providerGetter('test', 'infoProvider')();
  });

  it('should return nothing if not set', function() {
    inject(function(_info_) { info = _info_; });
    expect(info.getInfo()).toEqual('nothing');
  });

  it('should return the info that was set', function() {
    infoProvider.setInfo('something');
    inject(function(_info_) { info = _info_; });
    expect(info.getInfo()).toEqual('something');
  });
});
```

The provider for this test is very simple

```
    angular
        .module('test', [])
        .provider('info', info);

    function info() {
        var nfo = 'nothing';
        this.setInfo = function(s) { nfo = s; };
        this.$get = Info;

        function Info() {
            return { getInfo: function() {return nfo;} };
        }
    }
```

Not exactly sure how that translates to sinon, but providerGetter (which uses the angular-mocks functions) should work.